# PHP: Getting undefined variable message when variable is defined

Tags: php, class, variables

I'm following along with a beginner's PHP course and the current topic is classes. For some reason I am getting an undefined variable message for just one of the variables ($pages), but it still prints the variable value.

```
<?php 
    
    class Book { 
      public $title;
      public $author;
      public $pages;
    }
    
    $book1 = new Book;
    $book1->$title = "Harry Potter";
    $book1->$author = "JK Rowling";
    $book1->$pages = 400;

    echo $book1->$title;
    echo $book1->$author;
    echo $book1->$pages; 
 
  ?>
```

This is what prints

> Notice: Undefined variable: pages in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mywebsite/site.php on line 238
> Harry PotterJK Rowling
> Notice: Undefined variable: pages in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mywebsite/site.php on line 249
> 400

Comment: remove the `$` from the class properties: `echo $book1->title;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `$` when accessing the object.

Correct: `$book1->title`

Comment: For obvious TYPO's we dont write answers, a comment will suffice and then we delete the question as TYPO's are almost never any use to others

Comment: Alright, didn't know about that.